# ¿Cómo mostrar registros apartir de 3 tablas diferentes utilizando JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo las siguientes 3 tablas

**Salon**

```
ID      |   Nombre_Emp     |   Lugar     |     P   |

1       |   Ruiz           |     Y2      |     252 |
2       |   Maldonado      |     YR3     |     692 |
3       |   Salas          |     KL4     |     125 |
4       |   Rojas          |     P04     |     951 |
```

**Evento**

```
ID_evt |   Numero   |   CodInt  |  Nombre    |   Fecha       |   Hora      | 

1001   |      1     |     100    |  SANT     |   2016-10-03  | '03:00:00'  | 
1002   |      1     |     102    |  FNAT     |   2016-10-03  | '03:00:00'  | 
1003   |      1     |     103    |  HNAT     |   2016-10-03  | '03:07:00'  | 
1004   |      1     |     104    |  ENAT     |   2016-10-03  | '03:16:00'  |
```

**Nombre**

```
  CodNm   |   Nombre     |  

    100   |  SANTANA     |  
    102   |  FERNANDA    |  
    103   |  HENA        |  
    104   |  ELNA        |
```

con el siguiente query:

```
SELECT
  sa.ID
  sa.Nombre_Emp
  ev.Numero
  ev.CodInt
  nm.Nombre
FROM
  bdVet.Salon sa
  JOIN
  bdVet.Evento ev
  JOIN
  bdVet.Nombre nm
WHERE
  sa.ID = 1 AND ev.Numero = 1
```

Pero el resultado no es el esperado se me arroja mas de 200 resultados

***El resultado esperado es el siguiente:***

```
ID   |   Nombre_Emp   |  Numero   |   CodInt   |   Nombre
1    |     Ruiz       |     1     |    100     |   SANTANA
1    |     Ruiz       |     1     |    102     |   FERNANDA
1    |     Ruiz       |     1     |    103     |   HENA
1    |     Ruiz       |     1     |    104     |   ELNA
```

Como podria obtener el resultado anterior, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: intenta utilizando LEFT JOIN es vez de solo JOIN. no recuerdo mucho acerca del tema, pero **JOIN mostrará tódos las posibles combinaciones que se puedan hacer entre tus resultados**

Comment: Realmente el problema lo veo en que estas haciendo un join entre multiples tablas, pero solo estableces una relación entre dos de ellas (el Where) por lo que el resto de tablas te mostraran todo su contenido, y posiblemente intentando hacer todas las posibles combinaciones con los elementos de todas las tablas (algo bastante elebado y exponencial) Ahora te pongo algo que puedes intentar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes hacer un `inner JOIN` con los campos en común entre los registros de las tres tablas. He asumido las correspondencias que ves en las igualdades de los inner JOIN, si no son las correctas sustitúyelas por las que lo sean.

```
SELECT
      sa.ID
      sa.Nombre_Emp
      ev.Numero
      ev.CodInt
      nm.Nombre
    FROM bdVet.Salon sa 
    INNER JOIN bdVet.Evento ev ON sa.ID = ev.Numero
    INNER JOIN bdVet.Nombre nm ON mm.CodNm = ev.CodInt
    WHERE sa.ID = 1 AND ev.Numero = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Como te ponía en un comentario. Estas uniendo 3 tablas, y sin embargo solo estas imponiendo una condición entre dos de ellas, por lo que de las otras dos te mostrará todas las posibles combinaciones entre sus filas.

```
SELECT sa.ID, sa.Nombre_Emp, ev.Numero, ev.CodInt, nm.Nombre
FROM bdVet.Salon as sa
JOIN bdVet.Evento as ev ON ev.Numero = sa.ID
JOIN bdVet.Nombre as nm ON nm.CodNum = ev.CodInt
WHERE sa.ID = 1 AND ev.Numero = 1
```

Con esto lo que haces es: Primero que vas a seleccionar de que tablas.
Yo siempre uso "as" para estableces el "como" apodo a dicha tabla, para que sea más claro. Y luego en los join con ON declaras las relaccions entre las tablas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que está haciendo en definitiva tu consulta es un producto cartesiano, multiplicas los registros de cada tabla entre si, por eso te da un valor tan alto. El problema en la consulta es que estas estableciendo una relación entre tablas sin especificar cual es el campo por el cual establecer dicha relación.

No has especificado en tu ejemplo algún dato que nos permita saber si lo que necesitas es un `INNER JOIN` o un `LEFT  JOIN` la diferencia va a depender si quieres ver todos los salones independientemente que tengan o no eventos (`LEFT JOIN`) o bien solo te interesan los salones que han tenido eventos (`INNER JOIN`), usando este último ejemplo, tu consulta debiera ser así:

```
SELECT  sa.ID,
        sa.Nombre_Emp,
        ev.Numero,
        ev.CodInt,
        nm.Nombre
    FROM  bdVet.Salon sa
    INNER JOIN bdVet.Evento ev
        ON ev.Numero = sa.ID
    INNER JOIN bdVet.Nombre nm
        ON nm.CodNm = ev.CodInt
    WHERE   sa.ID = 1
```

Toma nota además, que al hacer el join de Salon y Evento ya no es necesario especificar en el where `ev.Numero = 1`

Answer (score 0):

primero le doy un consejo para cuando vaya a crear tablas relacionadas. Acostumbra a crear las llaves foráneas con el mismo nombre de la llave primaria de la tabla que vas a referenciar, esto en mi concepto para tener mejores practicas cuando necesitemos crear consultar muy largas que involucren INNER JOIN, ya que si haces lo que digo cuando necesites hacer un INNER JOIN entre dos tablas relacionadas simplemente sería.

```
SELECT id_jugador, nombres, apellidos, nombre_genero FROM jugador NATURAL JOIN genero; más la condición que quieres que se cumpla.
```

y si tiene más tablas sigue agregando NATURAL JOIN y el nombre de tu tabla.